# Docker volumes mounting, but changes aren't reflected

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers - a frontend (Next.js) and backend (NestJS). I run them both via docker-compose. The project structure is

```
project/
├─ frontend/
│  ├─ Dockerfile
├─ backend/
│  ├─ Dockerfile
├─ docker-compose.yml
```

**backend Dockerfile**

```
FROM node: alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn config set "strict-ssl" false
RUN yarn install --verbose
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["yarn","start:dev"]
```

**frontend Dockerfile**

```
FROM node: alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn config set "strict-ssl" false
RUN yarn install --verbose
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./packages/backend
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./packages/backend:/app
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    restart: always
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./packages/frontend
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./packages/frontend:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always
```

I have a problem with volumes. If I do docker-compose up and make code changes, it's getting reflected inside the container, but it's not reflected when I use the app.

For example, if I add a button to the frontend index.js, the button is also added to the frontend code inside the container (checked with docker exec -it container_id sh and then cat index.js), but If I refresh the app in the browser, the button is not there.

I run docker on Windows 10 with WSL 2.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

**Update: I finally got it working!**

The docker setup was correct, but there is no support for hot reloading inside docker containers for both Next.js and NestJS.

For Next.js, I configured webpack web middleware: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/6417
For NestJS, I used nodemon https://github.com/Nundy/doesn-t-hot-reload-issue/issues/1

For anyone interested, project starter is here: https://github.com/jochimv/Next.js-NestJS-dockerized-starter

I hope it will help someone out in the future.